# Limit of Bounded measurable function

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I got a problem stated as below.

> **Problem**   Suppose that $f$ is an integrable function and $g$ is a bounded measurable function. Then prove that $$ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \int f(x)\left[ g(x+t)-g(x) \right]dx =0  $$

At first moment, I came up dominated convergence theorem since 
$$|f(x)\left[g(x+t)-g(x)  \right]|\leq 2M|f(x)|  \hspace{3mm}\forall t .$$ But I could not prove that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} [g(x+t)-g(x)]=0 \hspace{4mm}a.e.$$
 For now, I cannot come up with another way to approach it. Should I change the way to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a standard fact that for any integrable function $f$, $\int |f(y+t)-f(y)|\, dy \to 0$ as $t \to 0$. [ Rudin's RCA has a proof]. Write the given integral as $\int [f(y-t)-f(y)] g(y)\, dy$ (by the substitution $y=x+t$) and pull out the sup of $|g|$]. This completes the proof. Some details about rewriting the given integral: $$\int f(x)[g(x+t)-g(x)]\, dx=\int f(x)g(x+t)\, dx-\int f(x)g(x)\, dx=\int f(y-t)g(y)\, dy -\int f(x)g(x)\, dx$$ by substitution. Hence $\int f(x)[g(x+t)-g(x)]\, dx= \int [f(y-t)-f(y)]g(y)\, dy$, so $|\int [f(y-t)-f(y)]g(y)\, dy| \leq M \int |f(y-t)-f(y)|\, dy$ where $M=\sup |g(x)|$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Could I ask how you switch $f$ and $g$? It seems substitution is not sufficient for me.

Comment: You have to first split the given expression into two separate terms and make the substitution only in the first term. The second term $\int f(x)g(x)\, dx$ remains untouched.

Comment: Great!  Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Try using Egorov's Theorem. Approximate the domain of integration by a compact set $K$. There is an $\epsilon > 0$ such outside a set of measure $\epsilon$ on $K$, the limit is uniform.

Hint 2: You could also change variables, to interchange $f$ and $g$ in the integral, with maybe a few sign changes. Then try to approximate $f$ in $L^1$ by a smooth compactly supported function.

For instance, see

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/245a-notes-2-the-lebesgue-integral/#more-4145

and

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/

for more about the first suggestion.